# Query for related products

Tags: php, mysql

I have detail page for products and i want to add a module of "related products".

In the db table "products" i store a value called "tags" for each product, something like "tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4".

Now i need to build a query that retrieve all products that match at least 2 of this tags, excluding the id of the main product displayed in the detail page. For example:

Main product

> Product Name | tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4

Related Products:

> Product Name | tag1, tag3, tag5
>
> Product Name | tag3, tag4, tag6, tag7

I'm not sure the best way to do that is SQL... maybe a PHP function using array?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way you can normalize the tags column? ie create 2 new tables: `tag` and `product_tag`

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: yes, I could have new tables...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a great idea to store a multi-valued attribute in a single field. Ideally, you would have a Products table, a Tags table and a ProductTags Table.

However, you could select the Tags for the Product and use `explode()` to get an array of Tags. The for each other product, do the same and use `array_intersect` to get an array of common elements. Then use `count() > 1` to determine if it's related

So:

```
function getRelatedProducts($productName)
{
    $productResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName = '$productName' LIMIT 0,1");

    $relatedProducts = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($productResults) == 1)
    {
        $product = mysql_fetch_array($productResults);
        $tags = explode(",",$product['tags']);

        $otherProducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName != '$productName'");

        while($otherProduct = mysql_fetch_array($otherProducts))
        {
            $otherTags = explode(",",$otherProduct['tags']);
            $overlap = array_intersect($tags,$otherTags);
            if(count($overlap > 1)) $relatedProducts[] = $otherProduct;
        }
    }

    return $relatedProducts;
}
```

It's a bit rough and ready but it should work. This code assumes you have columns called `productName` and `tags`.

[PHP:array_intersect - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

If you go ahead with a product_tags table, you can use the following code to find related products:

```
function getRelatedProducts($productId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT p.*,COUNT(*) AS matchedTags FROM products p
            INNER JOIN product_tags pt ON pt.product_id = p.id
            WHERE pt.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM product_tags WHERE product_id = $product_id)
            GROUP BY p.id
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";

    $results = mysql_query($sql);

    $relatedProducts = array();

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $relatedProducts[] = $result;
    }

    return $relatedProducts;
}
```

The important part is the SQL at the start of the function. It will give you the related products. Do with them what you will!

Comment: Thanx Brendan! Anyway, if you suggest me to have a tags table and a product_tags table i will move this way. But then, how i can query the db? I suppose that tags table should have: id, tag_name. And product_tags: id, product_id, tag_id

Comment: @Luciano That's exactly right. You can set a unique index between product_id and tag_id on the product_tags table to prevent duplicate tags on a product.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for the answers and the examples, was really helpful!

Comment: will [this](http://leonpanjtar.eu/web-design-blog/mysql-related-products-query/) example search fast ?

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that this,comma,separated,tag,list is not such a good idea. That's true, which I know the hard way.

If you MUST use it, you can use the table server to filter your result set with
    WHERE tag LIKE '%searchtag%'

But this search term is going to be quite slow, and is going to return false positive hits.
You're FAR better off creating a product_tags table with a row for each tag for each product.

Comment: you mean [this example](http://leonpanjtar.eu/web-design-blog/mysql-related-products-query/) with a `ProductTable` and `ProductTagsTable` and another `ProductsXTagsTable`  to hold connection between the products and tags table, or can you edit the post and show an example with a query to search fast on related products ?